# Mosquitto over SSL refuses publishing message

Tags: ssl, mqtt, ubuntu-18.04, mosquitto

I am having some trouble with Mosquitto (MQTT) over SSL (with letsencrypt).

I have it installed on a RoR Ubuntu 18.04 server, on Digital Ocean, with Nginx installed.

This setup worked perfectly for public messages.

Then, for communication over SSL, port 8883 is listening to all traffic on the domain name.

The ports are allowed in firewall.

My Problem is, whenever I try to publish over SSL, I get an error. Here's the full log:

```
$mosquitto_pub -d -h my-domain.xyz -t test -m "hello again" -p 8883 --capath /etc/ssl/certs/ -u “some-user” -P "p@s$w0rd"

Client mosqpub|23889-mosquitto sending CONNECT
Client mosqpub|23889-mosquitto received CONNACK
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Error: The connection was refused.
```

Here is my `../conf.d/default.conf`

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
​
listener 1883 localhost
​
listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.xyz/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.xyz/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.xyz/privkey.pem
```

Sample password file from `/etc/mosquitto/passwd`:

```
some-user:$6$SzAZtOMrxYGiECMU$1YMk4lnmY8FRTZj/vy1FLsnegsxx4OXSzX60rX7ej+muz1i6//16BKwkvwXYYYg2+7w9SRYaeuKPfA9Q==
```

Command to subscribe

```
mosquitto_sub -h domain.xyz -t "test" -u "some-user" -P "p@s$w0rd"
```

Log as found in `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.og`

```
1568255494: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1568255664: mosquitto version 1.4.15 terminating
1568523128: mosquitto version 1.4.15 (build date Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:42:22 -0300) starting
1568523397: mosquitto version 1.4.15 (build date Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:42:22 -0300) starting
1568523397: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1568523397: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1568523397: Error: Address already in use
1568523128: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1568523128: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1568523397: mosquitto version 1.4.15 terminating
```

When I run mosquitto client in blocking mode by manually providing the conf file, here's what I get:

```
$ mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf 
1568594709: mosquitto version 1.4.15 (build date Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:42:22 -0300) starting
1568594709: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf.
1568594709: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1568594709: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1568594709: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1568594709: Error: Unable to load CA certificates. Check cafile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.xyz/chain.pem".
```

Does it look like a permissions problem?

I followed the following guide, on an **Ubuntu 18.04** : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-the-mosquitto-mqtt-messaging-broker-on-ubuntu-16-04

What could be going wrong?

I can provide any other details that you want.

Comment: Assuming digital ocean vms are similar to aws, remove the `my-domain.xyz` from the `listener` lines

Comment: Also edit the question to include the full error message and the broker logs for startup and the connection

Comment: @hardillb Added both the details to the question, will also try without the domain name

Comment: @hardillb I have nginx reverse proxy installed. Could that have something to do with problem #2 ?

Comment: @hardillb I re-imaged the server, did everything from scratch, and now adding more details to the question (e.g., the fact that I have nginx installed, and that I ran mosquitto client manually with a conf file provided by hand)

Comment: With out knowing how ngix is setup that is impossible to answer. But the error about being able to open the ca chain file will need to be fixed.